# creating dsl editor in java

Tags: java, eclipse, dsl

I'm looking forward to create a Domain Specific Language editor in java.
I'm just starting up so i'm here to get some ideas where to start.
What i want is to create an interface like for my editor may be like eclipse (IDE) and i want it to work  like eclipse but for my language as eclipse do for java.
auto completion, spell checking, highlighting text auto end braces etc.
I've Goggled about the topic and i got this:
**XTEXT**

> "Building your own domain-specific languages has never been so easy.
>   Just put your grammar in place and you not only get the working parser
>   and linker but also first class Eclipse support."
>   As it says first class Eclipse support, i don't want eclipse support but i want a complete new interface for this. can i perform what i want using ***XTEXT*** or i should use something else?

Please guide me, do tell me if i'm wrong at some point here.
Thanks alot.

Comment: Yes, if you want to create a DSL editor in eclipse, then XText is your friend.

Comment: can i create a swing app and integrate xtext in JTextArea or something? What should i use for text editing i mean JTextArea or Pane?

Comment: You can do it, but it would be a lots of unnecessary work. Xtext comes with a lexer/parser part, and the UI part. The UI uses SWT (not swing) and integrates well in eclipse. You can use the parser part without the eclipse infrastructure, but I would not advise to try to reimplement the whole UI stuff in Swing.

Comment: means i can create whole UI of editor in XTEXT no need to use swing?

Comment: Yes. Eclipse uses another UI framework called SWT (Standard widget toolkit). It's a cross platform UI framework, which uses the native controls provided by the OS, but creates an easier-to-use Java interface on top of that. You will need to use that if you work with eclipse. The good news is, that if you plan to use Xtext you will (very) rarely manipulate the UI directly.

Comment: What about JEdit? i'm a bit confused right now. :/

Comment: I'm not familiar with JEdit.

Comment: okay i'm starting up XTEXT.. Hope its as easy to use as you're saying :)

Comment: It requires some work, but comes with really nice features :)